# Not able to create valid route53 entries with kubernetes Ingress in case of a failover routing.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-route53, failover

I created a kubernetes deployments scripts which will create two different deployments with associated services and the associated Ingress objects.

The creation of all the kubernetes objects (like deployments, services and ingress) are successful.

Regarding Ingress I am facing the problem with creating entries to Route53 failover routing in AWS.

Configurations used:

**Primary Failover attributes:**

external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/set-identifier: Failover
external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/aws-health-check-id: ""
external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/aws-failover: PRIMARY

**Secondary Failover attributes:**

external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/set-identifier: Failover
external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/aws-failover: SECONDARY

**The entries are creating successfully in Route53 for the Secondary Failover. But no entries are creating for Primary Failover mode. I tried all the possibilities I am aware.**

Even there is no error in ingress describe as well.

Please help me with any ideas or any workable configurations to create the Failover Routing in Route53 using kubernetes ingress.

Any help/suggestion is much appreciated.

Reference Used - https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md